# chrome extension will not append text int the current window

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

For A while now I have been trying to create an extension that will automatically insert a div at the beginning of the page you are on.  I am using the tutorial on this: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab page

This code on the tutorial works fine and it turns my page red when I click on the extension logo.

but if I replace:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor="red"
```

with:

```
$( "body" ).append( "<div>Testing123</div>" );
```

it doesn't work.

```
text = document.createTextNode("Hello. This is a new node.");
document.body.appendChild(text)
```

also does not work

Am I Getting the manifest permissions wrong?
Is there another way?

I have been scouring the forums for a long time and all the codes I tried did not work.

Comment: not really, it works using jsfiddle, but does not when I am using it in an extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no JQuery-Lib is included than your first approach can't work.
The second one works for me fine. Have you looked at the **bottom** of the page, cause body.append insert the text of course at the end. (Maybe you are looking at the top?)

Tested code:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Page Redder",
  "version": "2.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Make this page red"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**background.js**

```
// Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  // No tabs or host permissions needed!
  console.log('Turning ' + tab.url + ' red!');
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'text = document.createTextNode("Hello. This is a new node."); document.body.appendChild(text)'
  });
});
```

Comment: yeah, I was looking at the toop, thanks.  will try to get this to work